# How to keep file name when upload image Cloudinary with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, filenames, cloudinary

I can't keep file name when upload image to Cloudinary

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8n5b.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxBqc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i1gc.png

Comment: you can follow the documentation here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#including_a_path_in_the_public_id - You can specify a `public_id` or you can just use `use_filename:true` and `unique_filename:false` to keep the filename when uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.image, {
  public_id: req.body.imageName,
  resource_type: 'image'
});
```